# Exception caught by widgets library The following StateError was thrown building: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Firstly I'm very new to Flutter and this is basically my first project. I'm trying to make a chat app, with authentication with google, Firebase as the backend and trying to implement a search feature. By using the email of their google account they use and replacing the "@gamil.com" of the email and then making the remaining part of the email the person's username. I have added the search text field but when I hit the search button with a username it hits me this error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building:
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap - nterface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:82
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent - package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:100
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get - package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:115
#3      DocumentSnapshot.get - package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:45
#4      DocumentSnapshot.[] - package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:52
```

I'm completely lost I don't even know what parts of the code to attach so if anyone has any idea what I have to do here and what parts of my code I have to attach please let me know.

This is the link to the GitHub repository for the project - https://github.com/ArhamANZ/fam-chat-app